# PHP string comparasion

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I have a variable and its type is string. `var_dump()` shows:

`var_dump()` output is below:

```
string(14)
```

**//this is my code..**

`$game_cat = "Some text";` // some text mean actually it is one of below Category 1,2,3,4 ...

```
if ( $game_cat === "Category 1" ) {
        $cid = 1;
}

if ( $game_cat === "Category 2" ) {
        $cid = 2;
}

if ( $game_cat === "Category 3" ) {
        $cid = 0;
}

else{
       $cid = 999999;
}
```

For example when I change `$game_cat` to  Category 1 like `$game_cat = "Category 1";` $cid must 1 but output is 999999.

Why?

Comment: Try using `==`, if that works, then the strings might be the same value, but not EXACTLY the same. Notice your string has 14 characters while "Category 1" has 10, 12 including the double quotes

Comment: I tried it but it is not working

Comment: For string comparison he should have no difference between `==` and `===`. Double check that your capitalization is the same, and that you aren't appending extra spaces with `trim()`.

Comment: print_r the variable and let's see if it's actually what you say it is

Comment: $game_cat giving its value dynamically but when I do var_dump type and length is the same.

Comment: @RUJordan - In PHP there's only one data type to store strings. The reference to `==` would be relevant if we had e.g. `1` and `"1"`.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario what if `$game_cat` was created by concatenation?

Answer (score 3):

Use `elseif`

```
if ( $game_cat === "Category 1" ) {
        $cid = 1;
}

elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 2" ) {
        $cid = 2;
}

elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 3" ) {
        $cid = 0;
}

else{
       $cid = 999999;
}
```

What your current code does:

```
if ( $game_cat === "Category 1" ) {
        $cid = 1; //cid is 1
}

if ( $game_cat === "Category 2" ) {
        $cid = 2; //skipped
}

if ( $game_cat === "Category 3" ) {
        $cid = 0; //skipped
}

else{
       $cid = 999999; //cid == 999999
}
```

Comment: @hakiko he is correct, you are hitting the old `if this and for everything else` bug.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: **Working demo**:

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g02-bjj

Try this:

```
$game_cat = "Category 2";

if ( $game_cat === "Category 1" ) {
        $cid = 1;
}

elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 2" ) {
    $cid = 2;
}

elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 3" ) {
    $cid = 0;
}

else {
   $cid = 999999;
}
```

1. Use `elseif`: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php
2. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Hope it helps!

Comment: @hakiko take a look at the example, it's working: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/g02-bjj

Answer (score 1):

You're using multiple if-statements, while this should just be one (else-if). So, at first your variable will be 1, but because the last if-statement overwrites it, you'll get the wrong answer.

Do something like:

```
if ( $game_cat === "Category 1" ) {
        $cid = 1;
}
elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 2" ) {
        $cid = 2;
}
elseif ( $game_cat === "Category 3" ) {
        $cid = 0;
}
else{
       $cid = 999999;
}
```

For more information about elseif, check http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php :)

Answer (score 0):

Because of the last `else`. Since It's `"Category 1"` `$cid` will be set as `1` at the first `if` condition, however it will be reset because it's not `"Category 3"`.

You should use "elseif" instead of concatenating many "if" in this case.